# Angular 6: Error: Can't resolve './package' after installing google-translate-api

Tags: angular, npm, google-translate

I've just installed `google-translate-api` via `npm` with `npm install --save google-translate-api`. I didn't get any error message, but when I tried to run `npm start` it showed the following errors:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/got/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './package' in '/home/zolastro/Documents/Work/GenEnginePMV/genengine/GenEngine/node_modules/got'
ERROR in ./node_modules/osenv/osenv.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/home/zolastro/Documents/Work/GenEnginePMV/genengine/GenEngine/node_modules/osenv'
ERROR in ./node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'constants' in '/home/zolastro/Documents/Work/GenEnginePMV/genengine/GenEngine/node_modules/graceful-fs'
ERROR in ./node_modules/graceful-fs/fs.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/zolastro/Documents/Work/GenEnginePMV/genengine/GenEngine/node_modules/graceful-fs'
ERROR in ./node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/zolastro/Documents/Work/GenEnginePMV/genengine/GenEngine/node_modules/graceful-fs'
ERROR in ./node_modules/mkdirp/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/zolastro/Documents/Work/GenEnginePMV/genengine/GenEngine/node_modules/mkdirp'
ERROR in ./node_modules/got/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/home/zolastro/Documents/Work/GenEnginePMV/genengine/GenEngine/node_modules/got'
ERROR in ./node_modules/got/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in '/home/zolastro/Documents/Work/GenEnginePMV/genengine/GenEngine/node_modules/got'
ERROR in ./node_modules/os-homedir/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in '/home/zolastro/Documents/Work/GenEnginePMV/genengine/GenEngine/node_modules/os-homedir'
ERROR in ./node_modules/configstore/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/zolastro/Documents/Work/GenEnginePMV/genengine/GenEngine/node_modules/configstore'
ERROR in ./node_modules/mkdirp/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/zolastro/Documents/Work/GenEnginePMV/genengine/GenEngine/node_modules/mkdirp'
ERROR in ./node_modules/osenv/osenv.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/zolastro/Documents/Work/GenEnginePMV/genengine/GenEngine/node_modules/osenv'
ERROR in ./node_modules/xdg-basedir/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/zolastro/Documents/Work/GenEnginePMV/genengine/GenEngine/node_modules/xdg-basedir'
ERROR in ./node_modules/duplexer3/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/zolastro/Documents/Work/GenEnginePMV/genengine/GenEngine/node_modules/duplexer3'
ERROR in ./node_modules/get-stream/buffer-stream.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/zolastro/Documents/Work/GenEnginePMV/genengine/GenEngine/node_modules/get-stream'
ERROR in ./node_modules/got/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/zolastro/Documents/Work/GenEnginePMV/genengine/GenEngine/node_modules/got'
ERROR in ./node_modules/graceful-fs/legacy-streams.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/zolastro/Documents/Work/GenEnginePMV/genengine/GenEngine/node_modules/graceful-fs'
ERROR in ./node_modules/safe-eval/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vm' in '/home/zolastro/Documents/Work/GenEnginePMV/genengine/GenEngine/node_modules/safe-eval'
```

I've also read that it might be a sintax error in my `package.json`, but I don't see anything wrong there. Just in case, here it is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "gen-engine-web-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^6.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^2.1.3",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.10",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "firebase": "^5.0.4",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.6",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^2.0.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  }
}
```

Please, notice that I'm using Angular 6 and there isn't a Webpack configuration file (I've read several solutions regarding that file). Could anyone help me to solve this?