# Why I can't install package?

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to install google-translate-api and getting an error: `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './package' in '*:\***\node_modules\google-translate-api\node_modules\got'`.

But I have installed other packages and I didn't get error like this. I have a problem only for this package. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Show the relevant part of your package.json and show us the command you were trying to a) install and b) import the package.

Comment: ``"dependencies": { "google-translate-api": "^2.3.0" }`` In package.json

Comment: `npm install google-translate-api`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 6: Error: Can't resolve './package' after installing google-translate-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51705006/angular-6-error-cant-resolve-package-after-installing-google-translate-ap)

Comment: I'm using vue. And I didn't understand the problem.